# Is any manifold that can be parametrized with only one chart an affine space?

Tags: geometry, manifolds, affine-geometry

From Wikipedia:

An affine space is a set A together with a vector space $\overrightarrow{A}$, and a transitive and free action of the additive group of $\overrightarrow{A}$ on the set A.

Now let's say I have a manifold that is completely covered by just one chart $\phi: M \rightarrow \overrightarrow{A}$.
I can easily define an operation "$+$" between a Member of $M$ and an element of $\overrightarrow{A}$ by:

$$
m + v = \phi^{-1}(\phi(a) + v)
$$

That satisfies all of the required properties:
$$
m + 0 = \phi^{-1}(\phi(m) + 0) = \phi^{-1}(\phi(m)) = m
(m+v)+w = \phi^{-1}(\phi(m+v) + w) = \phi^{-1}(\phi(\phi^{-1}(\phi(m) + v)) + w)  \\
= \phi^{-1}(\phi(m) + v + w) = m + (v + w)
$$
I have to require that $\phi: M \rightarrow \overrightarrow(A)$ is surjective, so this proof works at every point and for every v.

By this definition, a general manifold could without any problem be an affine space, I just need to provide a more sophisticated "$+$" operation. Is this valid? My Intuition says that it shouldn't be.

Comment: Having a single chart makes a big difference, after all...

Comment: @paulgarrett do you suggest that the answer to the question is "yes"?

Comment: Ah, yes, and I think you wrote a proof... :)

Comment: This is a proof if the chart $\phi$ is _surjective_, but existence of such a chart is even more special than having a single chart. For example, an open annulus in the plane has one chart, but no surjective chart to the plane. (Without _some_ condition, we can't guarantee $\phi(a) + v$ is in the image of $\phi$.)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang yes, I should add that. It still baffle's me that a greater class than the (appearently to me) "flat spaces still counts as an affine space.

Comment: There's a principle (doubtless named, maybe "the transfer principle"...?) that if two sets $A$ and $B$ are in bijective correspondence by a mapping $\phi:A \to B$, then any structure on $B$ (such as that of an affine space) can be transferred to $A$ essentially "by asking the same question on $B$". What this means, if you like, is that "'structures' matter, not just the underlying set." If $A$ is an open ball (or a path segment...!) in an affine space, we wouldn't say "$A$ is an affine space" even though $A$ can be made into an affine space by a suitable bijection.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang yes, I thought so. In that case, the question should be reformulated as "Can we make a distinction between such spaces that "can" be made an affine space, and such spaces that we would say "are" an affine space". Maybe one can make the restriction that the structure mustn't depend on abitrary choices of coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on clarifications in the comments, let's write $(A, *)$ to connote an affine space, i.e., the underlying set $A$ of vectors *together with the addititonal structure* of displacements and affine scalings about points.

Now suppose $M \subset A$ has the same cardinality as $A$, and fix a bijection $\phi:M \to A$. The questions appear to be,

1. Can't we view $M$ as an affine space literally, and
2. Doesn't this flout common sense?

For the first, yes we can use the bijection $\phi$ to transfer the affine structure from $A$ to $M$, e.g., defining
$$
m +_{\phi} m' = \phi^{-1}(\phi(m) + \phi(m')),\quad m, m' \in M.
$$
This operation $+_{\phi}$ does literally comprise part of the structure of an affine space of $M$. It's also, to make a comical understatement, typically not equal to $+$. Chances are, the affine structure $*_{\phi}$ is so pathological it's uninteresting, analogous to obfuscated code, or to a pile of wood chips compared to a living tree.

To resolve the second, we need to examine "common sense" more carefully. When we breezily say "$M \subset A$ is an affine space," we mean "$M \subset A$ and $(M, *)$ is an affine space." In detail, "$(M, *)$ is an affine space" means $M$ is closed under affine translation and scaling *as defined in* $(A, *)$. In this sense, an open subset $M \subset A$ is an affine space if and only if $M = A$, which is presumably common sense.

Strictly, we cannot view a "bare set" such as $\mathbf{R}^{n}$ as being "a group" or "a vector space" or "a smooth manifold." In practice, the structure is usually understood (the additive group, the real vector space, the Euclidean manifold), and we get breezy. It's crucial to internalize, however, that these structures are accessories "sold separately." Different accessories (the rational vector space, the discrete topology) give the set different mathematical characteristics.

Regarding the final sentences of the question: An affine space (over the reals, say) can be viewed as a smooth manifold in a natural way, with the identity map as a global chart. A smooth manifold of positive dimension cannot, however, be naturally regarded as an affine space, even if $M$ is an open subset of an affine space diffeomorphic to the whole space. Loosely, this would be possible only if *all* diffeomorphisms $M \to A$ induced *the same affine structure*.

Comment: About your last paragraph, the magic word here is the "naturally", as it denotes that the affine structure is independent of the choice of the diffeomorphism?

Comment: In a word, yes. I'm using _naturally_ in an informal sense, but the manifold structure does not uniquely determine an affine space structure. (In the same spirit, we might say a vector space is naturally viewed as an affine space, or that an affine space with a distinguished point is naturally viewed as a vector space.)