# Is any set that can be bijectively maped to a vectorspace itself a vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces

This is a follow up to my [last question on affine spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4400406/is-any-manifold-that-can-be-parametrized-with-only-one-chart-an-affine-space), when I realized that I could as well extend the question to vector spaces

If I am given a set $S$ and a bijective map $\phi$ to a vector space $V$ over $K$, then I can straightforward define a "+" operation and a "*" operation for elements of this set:

$$
+:S\times S \rightarrow S \\
s_1 + s_2 :=\phi^{-1}( \phi(s_1) +_v \phi(s_2))  \\
*: K \times S \rightarrow S \\
k * s := \phi^{-1}(k*_v \phi(s))
$$
I'm basically just using that the vector Space is already equiped with addition $+_v$ and multiplication $*_v$. By that, a large group of sets can be "made" a vector space.
Or is the catch here that a set itself is not a vector space, but instead the pairing "S, "+", "*" is the vector space?

Comment: Let $K$ be a field and $x\in K$. Then $V=\{x\}$ is only a vector space for $x=0$, but all singletons are in bijection.

Comment: What you're doing is called transport of structure: you're equipping a simple structure (a set) with the more complex structure of another object (a vector space) using an isomorphism with regards to the simple structure (isomorphism of sets are simply the bijections). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_of_structure

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos the interesting question then is wether there is any way to distinguish "Vector-spaces" from "sets that can be made vector spaces".

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly the catch: whether a collection is a vector space depends not just on the collection, but also the addition and scalar multiplication operations. Choose a different set of operations and it will have different properties.

As you say, it is $(S,+,*)$ which is the vector space.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example is the set $S=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid y=x^2\}.$ The bijection is to $\mathbb R,$  with $(x,y)\mapsto x.$

Is $S$ a vector space? We can make it a vector space, by defining addition and multiplication, but without defining them, it is not a vector space, and it is not a vector subspace of $\mathbb R^2$ given the usual vector space addition and scalar multiplication there. We can define a vector space structure on $S,$ but in general the operations might end up very strange, tailored as they are to match the particular bijection.

For another example, if $V$ is a vector space, we can define a bijection, for each $w\in V,$ as $f_w:v\mapsto v+w.$ Using the bijection, you get different definitions of the vector space structure on the set $V.$ So you get two new operators, $+_w$ and $\cdot_w$ for $v_1,v_2\in V$ and $r\in \mathbb R,$ where:

$$v_1+_wv_2=v_1+v_2+w\\r \cdot_w v_1=r\cdot v_1+(r-1)\cdot w$$

With these operations, the zero vector is $0_w=-1\cdot w.$ Then $(V,+_w,\cdot_w,0_w)$ is a different vector space structure on the set $V.$

Of course, $f_w$ is a relatively nice bijection. There are infinitely many bijections $V\to V$ that are less nice, and writing down the specific operations might be ugly.

---

Ultimately, when being pedantic, we will write “$(V,+,\cdot,0)$ is a vector space over the field $k.$” A vector space is not a set, it is a set with some operations. In that sense, $V$ is not even a vector space, because we haven’t specified the operations.

But we tend to avoid that pedantry when it is unnecessary, and treat “$V$ is a vector space over $k$” to mean the same thing.

When you get to category theory, you’ll learn that the “functor” which sends the vector space $(V,+,\cdot,0)$ to the underlying set $V$ is called a forgetful functor, and lots of categories have such a forgetful functor with the same property.

If $Y$ is a topological space, and $f:X\to Y$ is a set bijection, we can define a unique topology on $X$ where $f$ is a homeomorphism.

If $R$ is a ring, and $S\to R$ is a bijection, we can define unique operations on $S$ to make the bijection an isomorphic ring.

But these are not inherent in the sets. They are inherent in the bijection and the structure on the range.

Choose different vector space operations on the set $V,$ or a different bijection $S\to V,$ yields a different vector space structure  on $S.$  We treat the bijection as a source for “renaming” the elements of $V.$ So if $S=\{1,2,3\}$ and $T=\{a,b,c\}$ and the bijection $1\mapsto a,2\mapsto b,3\mapsto c,$ then a structure on $T$ yields a structure on $S$ just by “renaming” $a$ to $1,$ $b$ to $2,$ and $c$ to $3.$